# MySQL: How could i do search in mysql with same meaning part in word?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I have a problem on trying to do search by same meaning words in japanse, like i have a table of same meaning words:

```
| Column A | Column B             |
| -------- | --------             |
| きず      | きず、傷、疵、キズ、瑕  |
| 株式会社   | 株式会社、㈱、（株）    |
| aa       | aa,bb,cc,dd          |
```

that all words listed in Column B have the same meaning.

then when i do search in another table with " somethingaa " or "somethingbb".., i have to make a regex string to search like
 `Select NAME from table USER where job REGEXP "somethingaa|somethingbb|somethingcc|somethingdd";`

but if i search with words like "IGOaaONbbANDaa", this make regex much more diffical and longer.

Can anyone show me the better way to perform searching same meaning word like this?

Im doing this on Spring MVC + Mysql. Thankyou

Comment: You must normalize your table. It must contain 2 columns, and each must store only one word. I.e. (custom word - canonical word). In this case you may check for custom word presence by provided canonical word using simple joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this:

```
CREATE TABLE datatable (id INT, phrase TEXT);
INSERT INTO datatable VALUES
(1, 'word01 word02 word03'),
(2, 'word01 word03 word05'),
(3, 'word02 word04 word06');
```

```
CREATE TABLE criteria (
  canonicalword VARCHAR(255),
  customword VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO criteria VALUES
('01', '01'),
('01', '07'),
('01', '08'),
('05', '05'),
('05', '06'),
('09', '03'),
('09', '05'),
('09', '07'),
('09', '09');
```

```
SET @criteria := '01';
-- rows 1 and 2, immediate
SELECT DISTINCT datatable.*
FROM datatable
JOIN criteria ON datatable.phrase REGEXP CONCAT('word', criteria.customword)
WHERE criteria.canonicalword = @criteria;
```

| id | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word01 word02 word03 |
| 2 | word01 word03 word05 |

```
SET @criteria := '05';
-- row 2, immediate
-- row 3, via '05' => '06'
SELECT DISTINCT datatable.*
FROM datatable
JOIN criteria ON datatable.phrase REGEXP CONCAT('word', criteria.customword)
WHERE criteria.canonicalword = @criteria;
```

| id | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | word01 word03 word05 |
| 3 | word02 word04 word06 |

```
SET @criteria := '09';
-- row 1, via '09' => '03'
-- row 2, via '09' => '03' and '05', DISTINCT applied
SELECT DISTINCT datatable.*
FROM datatable
JOIN criteria ON datatable.phrase REGEXP CONCAT('word', criteria.customword)
WHERE criteria.canonicalword = @criteria;
-- the same, w/o DISTINCT, row2 is returned twice
SELECT datatable.*
FROM datatable
JOIN criteria ON datatable.phrase REGEXP CONCAT('word', criteria.customword)
WHERE criteria.canonicalword = @criteria;
```

| id | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word01 word02 word03 |
| 2 | word01 word03 word05 |

| id | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word01 word02 word03 |
| 2 | word01 word03 word05 |
| 2 | word01 word03 word05 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FL3wZxk_)

Comment: oh thank. i understand the way the engine work. but for extend, my website can search multiple words, i can search for "word01 text02", that mean i have to duplicate condition form for each part "word01" and "text02". any better idea?

Comment: and when i seach for  word01 or word07 its also need to return result for '01' as defined in your "criteria" table, then i have to create data like
 ('01', '01'),
('01', '07'),
('01', '08'),
('07', '01'),
('07', '07'),
('07', '08'),
('08', '01'),
('08', '07'),
('08', '08'),
am i understanding in the right way? to detect which part or the word that could be citeria word

Comment: @MonYanglake *my website can search multiple words* Search for each word, then aggregate and count the amount of found words, return rows where it is equal to total words amount. *then i have to create data like* This differs from your task. If you have not (canonical-custom) but a group of peer/equal words then the table must be (group number - word), and you must use 2 copies of this table obtaining the whole group words by one of them.

Comment: i see, i'll take a test 1st. thank for your answer since i am too new that cant upvote